# Badge notification should support hover description like profile page badges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

When a "you've earned the  badge" notification is displayed, it would be very nice if the badge name could be hovered over to display the badge description. Currently to discover what that badge means, you need to go to the profile page, find that badge, and hover over it there. Seems like it could all be done inline.

Comment: It should not hover, but link included in the notification( to be touch devices friendly)

Answer (score 1):

We actually want users to go to this page, though.

Comment: why is that important?

Comment: So link should be included in the notification( but not hover)